# Matlab - vpasolve is very slow if no solution exists

Tags: matlab

I got a problem with the performance of vpasolve. I want to numerically solve one equation in one symbolic variable (I search for solutions only in a specified interval). Whenever there is a solution, performance is fine, vpasolve finds it in about 1-2s. However, if there is no solution, then vpasolve takes very long time to realize that (about 40-80s).

Anything I can do to improve performance? I'm doing a simulation, so vpasolve is called around 50.000 times, so 40-80s is way too long. Digits is set to 7 already.

thanks a lot,

SZ

Comment: how about `fsolve` https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html and you can adjust the tolerances etc to stop searching for a solution

Comment: How can I use fsolve? I have an equation "dSWF=0" with symbolic variable "LE". With vpasolve I did "vpasolve(dSWF==0,LE,[0 L])". Now I tried fsolve(@(xy)subs(dSWF,LE,xy),0) but doesnt work, says "SOLVE requires all values returned by functions to be of data type double."